# How to use ADOMD.net in MVC project?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, adomd.net

I'm using `ADOMD.net` to access data from a cube, initially I was using Windows 7 and SQL Server 2008 and I had no problem, for example I was loading all catalogs into a datatable like this:

```
DataTable objTable = mdConnection.GetSchemaDataSet(AdomdSchemaGuid.Catalogs, null).Tables[0];
```

And then I switch to Windows 8 and SQL Server 2012, when I call the same line of code my datatable is always empty.

My project is a MVC project, but if I try the same using a Winforms project it works fine.

Does anyone know something about this?

Comment: Is the problem that the DataTable object is empty, or that the page is not displaying the data?

Comment: The DataTable object is allways empty, not just for Catalogs but also Cubes, Measures, etc.

Comment: Then it has nothing to do with Winforms.

Comment: It sounds like this is permissions related. The MVC app is probably trying to connect as some type of IIS user. Detect which user attempts to connect from Windows and also from MVC. Then compare the permissions for each user and make the necessary adjustments for the MVC user.